# show/hide toggle for subpages in wordpress admin area

Tags: wp-admin, pages

We have a wordpress site using many subpages to each page - I'm looking to create a show/hide accordion toggle within the backend to show and hide subpages allowing us to keep the page listings clear.

Does anyone know of a plugin to do this? I've had a google but not much joy so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageMash looks like it does that: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagemash/ and http://joelstarnes.co.uk/blog/pagemash/

Comment: There's also [CMS Tree Page View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/)

Comment: thanks, didn't know about that one, it looks very good.

Comment: Thanks Simon, looks like it will do the trick! not keen on the styling would prefer to keep the default look but can hopefully change in the CSS. @t31os the Tree View looks cool too - will check both. Appreciated. Andy